# Conditional ensure in use-package

Tags: use-package

Basically, I want to ensure that the `elfeed` package is available and load it with `use-package`, but only on one computer, so I wrote something like this:

```
(unless (string= system-name "here-elfeed-shall-not-run")
  (use-package elfeed
    :ensure t
    :config
     (setq elfeed-feeds '(blabla doesnt matter))))
```

The problem is that even though the use-package part is not supposed to run (because system-name == "here-elfeed-shall-not-run"), it, in fact, runs.
I dealt with this by using an if keyword:

```
(use-package elfeed
  :if (not (string= system-name "here-elfeed..."))
  ...)
```

Which would be great, if I could still ensure that elfeed is available on the computer on which I want it to be.

What can I do to ensure that elfeed exists on one PC, but shouldn't be downloaded on the other?

Comment: If you're sure that the package is getting installed by use-package (and not by some other forgotten code you have) then you should file an issue at use-package.

Comment: Yes, use-package installs `:ensured` packages at macro-expansion-time, which seems like a bug, but is probably a feature.

Answer (score 2):

No need to complicate things. The code is as simple as:

```cl
(unless (or (string= system-name "here-elfeed-shall-not-run")
            (package-installed-p 'elfeed))
  (package-install 'elfeed))
```

Comment: While the idea behind this answer is fine, it would be best if you addressed the multiple PCs thing.

Comment: Just combine this with an un-`:ensured` use-package directive as 2 forms inside the `(unless ....)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out there's a keyword one can use to fix this: `:unless`, though it still needs elisp's unless, otherwise it throws an error.

```elisp
(unless (string= system-name "here-elfeed-shall-not-run")
  (use-package elfeed
    :unless (string= system-name "here-elfeed-shall-not-run")
    :ensure t
    :config
      (setq elfeed-feeds '(blabla doesnt matter))))
```

Comment: `:unless` (and `:if`) currently don't affect `:ensure`, see [use-package #190](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/190). The outer `unless` can't be doing anything since it only affects runtime, not macroexpansion.